# Logback+SLF4J does no log in JavaEE 7 application

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, logback, slf4j, payara

I'm building a simple app and now i'm facing the "logging nightmare" on javaee application. I've done days of searches, hundreds of change/test but there's no way to make it run.
My app is made of a simple

```
  EAR
   +-- /lib
   |     +-- slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
   |     +-- logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
   |     +-- logback-core-1.2.3.jar
   |
   +-- JAR (JPA/EJB/Producers/Interceptors)
   |    +--src/main/resources
   |        +-- logback.xml
   |        +-- logback-test.xml
   |
   +-- WAR
```

The libs are so loaded in the lib directory of the EAR file.
my **pom.xml** in the EJB project contains this dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

there is also the *javaee-api-7.0* as provided.
I'm putting log facility inside the EJB project so I can use the log producer in the webapp and inject the logger also inside the JSF controllers.
The **logback.xml** is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="c:/Dev" />

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
                  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>WE:%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="it.univaq.we2018" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

All my classes are under the **it.univaq.we2018** package (.service, .controllers, ....).
Here is the CDI producer (the System.out are there just for my purposes):

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class LoggerProducer {
    @Produces
    public Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint ip) {
        System.out.println("-----> construct logging for: "+ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass());
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass());
        System.out.println("-----> LogFactory is: "+log+" for "+log.getName()); 
        return log;
    }
}
```

This is an EJB where it's used:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class SecurityService implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    Logger log;

    public boolean performSecurityCheck(String userName, String target) {        
        log.debug("Testing ["+target+"] for user ["+userName+"]...");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The package of the *Logger* and *LoggerFactory* is **org.slf4j**
Tried to move the logback.xml under every folder/package...nothing. The output is always the same:

```
INFORMAZIONI:   indexController.init() INFORMAZIONI:   ---- ENTER:
[it.univaq.we2018.tutor.controller.IndexController.doAction()]

INFORMAZIONI:   -----> construct logging for: class
it.univaq.we2018.tutor.service.SecurityService

INFORMAZIONI:   -----> LogFactory is: 
Logger[it.univaq.we2018.tutor.service.SecurityService]
for it.univaq.we2018.tutor.service.SecurityService

INFORMAZIONI:  10:38:34.423 [http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] DEBUG
it.univaq.we2018.tutor.service.SecurityService - Testing
[it.univaq.we2018.tutor.controller.IndexController.doAction()] for
user [null]...

INFORMAZIONI:   indexController.doAction() INFORMAZIONI:  
BaseService.businessMethod() INFORMAZIONI:   ---- EXIT: 
[it.univaq.we2018.tutor.controller.IndexController.doAction()]
```

The log row #4 is the one that should go to the file but the file is never opened and the format of the log is not consistent with the configuration (should start with **WE:** prefix and have different pattern).
I don't know how to fix this. I always thought that the logging of JavaEE application needed a complete redesign from the ground-up: the appserver should provide a "plugin" mechanism like the datasource that reduces all of this problem related to configuration, classloading, lib clashing and so on.

Running on NetBeans 8.2 maven javaee7 archetype project, Java 1.8_172 under Payara 5.182.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a resource visibility problem.

Jars in the EAR/lib directory cannot see classes or resources in EJB jars or WAR files. Your configuration currently appears to be in an EJB module. Therefore the log-back classes in the EAR/lib directory cannot see the configuration files.

If you must package your logging configuration then it will need to be in a jar that is in the EAR/lib directory for it to be found.

More information on visibility of resources and classes within an EAR file can be found in my answer to [My ear is not able to find ejb module classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306341/my-ear-is-not-able-to-find-ejb-module-classes/41310413#41310413).

Personally, I prefer to externalise logging configuration. In the case of log-back you can specify a path to the config file using the `-Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Moved the logback libraries in another JAR and included into the project. Starting it up it looked in the ebj-jar file (saw a message in the log of Payara). So I just moved the file logback.xml into the META-INF of the ejb-jar and voilà..it started!