# JAR library in WAR module not seen

Tags: maven, jar, war, ear

I have Maven project with WAR and EAR module. EAR module has WAR as a dependency and is included as a war module in `maven-ear-plugin`. There's also JAR library added in EAR module and is used by WAR module.

EAR module pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>MyEar</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>MyWar</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>war</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>MyJar</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <modules>
                            <jarModule>
                                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                                <artifactId>MyJar</artifactId>
                            </jarModule>
                            <webModule>
                                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                                <artifactId>MyWar</artifactId>
                                <contextRoot>/MyWebApp</contextRoot>
                            </webModule>
                        </modules>
                        <version>6</version>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

</project>
```

And WAR module pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>MyWar</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyJar</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm trying to build EAR that includes MyWar and MyJar in root. The problem is that if I use EAR pom like the one above, MyJar library is not "seen" by MyWar.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you defined `<packaging>ear</packaging>`? Furthermore it would be helpful to have the full pom file otherwise it's hard to guess...

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, `packaging` is set to `ear`. Full EAR pom is added.

Comment: @khmarbaise Should I put MyJar in WAR's manifest file? How can I do that in Maven?

Comment: If this is the literal pom then I don't really see how this even builds, given that you define no dependency version for the 'myJar' module.

Comment: @Gimby This is a literal EAR pom. JAR version is defined in parent project pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only modules that should be in the root of the EAR archive are ejb-jars, wars and rars.

Utility library jars should be placed in a "lib" directory within the EAR.

You just need to add one line to your EAR plugin configuration to accomplish this:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <jarModule>
                            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                            <artifactId>MyJar</artifactId>
                        </jarModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                            <artifactId>MyWar</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/MyWebApp</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                    <version>6</version>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>  <--- this!
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

If you're going to be using EAR files you should familiarise yourself with the class visibility rules for the various modules within them. This is loosely summarised in [My ear is not able to find ejb module classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306341/my-ear-is-not-able-to-find-ejb-module-classes/41310413#41310413).

*In general you should not be using EAR files these days. In most cases a simple WAR file will be sufficient*

Comment: thank you for your help. I managed to put jars in ear as I've wanted and my app works. Just out of curiosity, why shouldn't I use EAR files?

Comment: Because not very many people understand the class visibility rules in them. A WAR file is much simpler (you can put EJBs in them now). Generally everyone has enough complexity to deal with without worrying whether a component can see your classes when they're in an EAR file.